# Check user Authorization for certain Service methods in go-kit with JWT

Tags: go, authorization, jwt

I'm fairly new to go-kit and micro-service architecture as well.

I have a JWT that contains the authenticated user's id as a claim, and each service's method, I want to check if the user has permission to update its own **client** record, but it seems that wherever I put it, it feels wrong. What are the best practices to doing something like this?

```
// client.go
type Client struct {
    ID     string `json:"id"`
    UserID string `json:"user_id"`
    // ...
}

type ClientDataLayer interface {
    Load(db *sql.DB, id string) *Client
    Update(db *sql.DB, cl *Client) *Client
    // ... more CRUD methods
}
```

Doing it within a service middleware I would have to call another service's method which seems to break the purpose of the architecture:

```
// service.go
type Service interface {
    UpdateClient(ctx context.Context, cl *Client) (*Client, error)
    // ... more methods
}

func NewClientService(db *sql.DB, cdl ClientDataLayer) {
    // ....
}

type service struct {
    db  *sql.DB
    cdl ClientDataLayer
}

func (svc *service) UpdateClient(ctx context.Context, id string) (*Client, error) {
    return nil, nil
}

// service middleware
type accessControl struct {
    svc Service
}

func (ac *accessControl) UpdateClient(ctx context.Context, cl *Client) (*Client, error) {
    // ... get token and claims from context
    // scopes := jwt.Claims().Get("scopes")

    // Here I don't have the client's user_id, 
    // and it does not feel right to call another service's method
    if !strings.Contains(scopes, "client:write") || cl.UserID != userID {
        return nil, errors.New("forbidden")
    }

    // ...
    return nil, nil
}
```

Doing it on the endpoint its pretty much the same

```
// transport.go
func makeUpdateClientEndpoint(svc Service) endpoint.Endpoint {
    return func(ctx context.Context, request interface{}) (interface{}, error) {
        // type cast request
        // ... get token and claims from context
        // scopes := jwt.Claims().Get("scopes")

        // Same problem as before, I don't have the client's user_id

        if !strings.Contains(scopes, "client:write") || cl.UserID != userID {
            return nil, errors.New("forbidden")
        }

        cl, _ := svc.UpdateClient(ctx, request.ClientID)

        // ...

        return nil, nil
    }
}
```

I probably could get away by using the ClientDataLayer to retrieve the client and checking the user's id. As a way to avoid messing with another service method to load the client because it may have middlewares for logging or metrics too.

How could I achieve this without so much hassle where I feel like breaking the patterns?

Comment: have you tried using [auth/jwt](https://github.com/go-kit/kit/tree/master/auth/jwt) package from go-kit?

Comment: Yes, but it handles authentication, what I need is authorization

Comment: I need a similar functionality, did you find any solution? thanks